# signing my application using keytool

Tags: android, facebook, keytool

well i am stuck on this step too

> $ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64 Enter keystore password: android

please any body explain it

Comment: If you want to sign your application, you need to use jarsigner. Keytool is usually used to generate the certificate with which you sign your app. It's a two stage process, generate the key first, then sign the app.

Comment: i dont understand this to lines i am trying to sign it to upload the hash key to my face book app on these tutorial [link]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#register

Answer (score 0):

after i tried on cmd i get it and it do as follow 
first locate keytool in your system by cd \path\
after that write this line as it is

```
$ keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

and this one mean  ~/.android/debug.keystore
the path where your keystore exported from eclips

and to make sure that the hashkey generated is really right the cmd should ask you about the password you use to generate keystore